# Laravel 5 login without password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using an API wherein I want to login the user. The only information that I have is his/her email.

How will I be able to authenticate that user without having to insert his/her password?

Here's the code that I tried.

```
public function linkedinLogin()
{
     $email = json_decode($_POST['email']);


     Session::put('linkedin_email', $email);


     //$value = session('linkedin_email');

    if (Session::has('linkedin_email')) Auth::login(Session::get('linkedin_email'));

        return $value;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the linkedInemail in your db?

Comment: None, only Users table.

Comment: Why dont you just get the user using the email id and login it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you have to pass App\User to the Auth::login function, but you are passing an email address. This will not work.

What I suggest is doing one of two things:

1. Find the ID of the user associated with that linkedin_email and use the Auth::loginUsingId(id) to authenticate the user. or,
2. Find the user associated with that linkedin_email and pass the $user to the Auth::login function.

For Example:

```
$user = App\User::where('linkedin_email', $value)->get()->first();

Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: Thanks broo. Works accordingly. :)